# Opaque Legend Box

Tags: r, plot, transparency, legend

I was wondering how I could go about creating an opaque legend box in R for my plots?  I've tried using bg="grey", but the lines on the graph are still covering the legend.

Comment: can you post your code? you probably just need to call legend after you call points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use bg="white" (or any other color, as you already did) *and* you have to draw the legend after you plot the lines/points/grid/etc.

For example:

```
plot(...)
lines(...)
grid(...)
legend(...) # legend has to be the last command!
```

Comment: It worked!  My problem was that my legend was not the last command.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but there is another way to do this than has been presented thus far.

Just use the following statement when creating your legend:

```
bg=make.transparent("red",0.8)
```